# GDB: getting exact memory address not < Address 0x4 out of bounds >

Tags: c++, gdb, memory-address

Is it possible to get the exact address value of strs[i] before initialization, not "< Address 0x4 out of bounds >"?? if possible, then how?

```
(gdb) list
15  int main()
16  {
17    int j, i;
18    char *strs[4];
19  
20    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
21    {
22      strs[i] = new char [11];
23    }
24        
25    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
26    {
27      init(strs[i]);
28    }
29  
30    for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
31    {
32      cout << strs[j] << endl;
33    }
34  
35    return(0);
36  
37  }
```

Below is the value of strs[i]:

```
(gdb) p strs[i]
$4 = 0x4 < Address 0x4 out of bounds >
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "exact initial address"? What more do you want to know other than that `strs[i]` has value `0x4` which is out of bounds?

Comment: I noticed you changed the index in your question. Did you also change it in the code you are testing? Do you still get the wrong answer?

Comment: I got it. I'm sorry, did something wrong on the testing. this is embarrassing. :(

Answer (score 2):

This is no good:

```
   char *strs[4];
   for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
```

Arrays are indexed starting from 0.  There is no such element as `strs[4]`, which is why you are going out of bounds.  The address is meaningless.